# How to do animation in Tilemap using LibGdx?

Tags: android, android-animation, libgdx, tiles

I am using tile map in my Game but i am facing problem that how to move object in **tile map** or  start animation???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not animate your `TileMap` or any tile of your map. 
You animate `Actors` at a `Stage`. And the `TileMap`is the background of the `Stage`for example.
 If you want something betweeen `MapLayer` you draw the backgroundlayer and than the foregroundlayer.

There is already a AnimatedTiledMapTile but as fare as i see there is no implementation for that yet. For example the `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` does ignore those `Tiles`. And it wouldnt make sense if you start moving a Tile from the map! The animation would be something like fire or water on the ground so it changes it's texture or such.

 If you want to move your `TileMap` you can attach it to a Actor and animate the Actor or simple move the camera.

 so in short. You do not animate your `Tiles` you do animate your `Actors` of your `Stage` you use. They should be in front of your `MapLayer`

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. But I want to move **Tilemap** object rather than whole  **TileMap**. My  **TileMap** is moving with the help of camera. Is there any solution how to move object(Cell) of  **TileMap**?

Comment: Not that i know as i said. You cant move single Tile. Make an Actor that represent the tile and move it. That should look exactly the same. It would be against a Tilemap logic if you move tiles out of the square system... so i wouldnt do that.

Comment: There is implementation for AnimatedTiledMapTile, but it does not serve the purpose of moving player in a map, it is used to animate a single tile (as you would animate a tile of fire for example).

Comment: regulary you do not move tiles. If you want to move one you create a tilemap and move an object on top of it. For example the player ontop of the tilemap. Those should be seperate "layer".

Comment: you can create an object layer in the map that represents the Sprites or Actors that you want to move.

Comment: @AshrafSayied-Ahmad yes you could but I wouldn't recommend to do so since you want to change actors a lot and this would reduce the performance of the tiled map. Simply use a stage and overlay it.